# "$git push heroku master" is using the wrong account

Tags: git, heroku, command-line-interface

I cannot seem to change my account to push to heroku.  When I do "$git push heroku master" it tells me that accountA@mail.com does not have access.  However, "$heroku whoami" shows accountB@mail.com.  No matter what I try, it shows that I am logged in with accountB@mail.com but tries to push to heroku with accountA@mail.com.

I have tried "$heroku login".  It changes my account but does not let me push to heroku with that account.

I have tried https://github.com/heroku/heroku-accounts with "$heroku accounts:set accountB" and it does the same thing.  Changes the whoami, but does not let me push with that account.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution to this, that honestly is not ideal, but it works.  I went to the Heroku website and logged in with accountB.  Then I just gave permission to accountA@mail.com.

login > my_app > Access > "Add collaborator"

It's not ideal and not how I would like to do it, but it works and I got sick of trying to solve it and was just glad for any solution.